# How to create page that lists tags by initial letter?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, pages, tags, list

I want to create a page that lists tags that begin with a specific letter. So for example I want a page that lists all tags that begin with the letter 'A'. This is the code I got so far

```
<?php $args = array('name__like' => "a", 'order' => 'ASC');
    $terms = get_terms('post_tag', $args);
    if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        $count = count($terms);
        $i=0;
        $term_list = '<ul class="my_term-archive">';
        echo '<h2 class="term-letter">A</h2>';
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $i++;
            $term_list .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
            if ($count != $i) {
                $term_list .= '';
            }
            else {
                $term_list .= '</ul>';
            }
        }
        echo $term_list;
    }
    ?>
```

The problem is it's not listing all tags that begin with the letter A instead it lists anything that contains the letter 'A'. How can I fix this?

Another question: Is there a more effective way to create separate pages for all 27 alphabetical letters? cause I don't want to manually create them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Question's Answer:**

For filtering based on your terms first letter you need to filter the query, which you can do with the `terms_clauses` hook. By putting the below code block in your theme's `functions.php` you can do that-

```
function the_dramatist_filter_term_clauses( $clauses ) {
    remove_filter('term_clauses','the_dramatist_filter_term_clauses');
    $pattern = '|(name LIKE )\'%(.+%)\'|';
    $clauses['where'] = preg_replace($pattern,'$1 \'$2\'',$clauses['where']);
    return $clauses;
}
add_filter('terms_clauses','the_dramatist_filter_term_clauses');
```

**Second Question's Answer:**

I don't think you need to create separate 27 pages for every letter. Rather you can use [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable to do that for you. By using this `$_GET` variable you can pass the letter as parameter that you need to be and catch this to `$name__like = isset($_GET['your_get_variable name']) ? $_GET['your_get_variable name'] : '';`. Then pass it to `$args` array. The array will look like below-

```
$name__like = isset($_GET['your_get_variable name']) ? $_GET['your_get_variable name'] : '';
$args = array(
    'name__like' => $name__like, 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'hide_empty' => 0 // Put 0 If you need to show the empty terms otherwise 1
);
```

Hope that helps.